# SSL on all kafka cluster nodes

Tags: ssl, apache-kafka

I am planning to deploy Kafka cluster. I have below query :

1) To secure producer and consumer communication with Kafka broker, SSL can be used. If I have a cluster of 9 brokers and 3 zookeeper nodes and if I do not want to use self-signed certificates, do I have to buy a certificate for each of the nodes (9 + 3 certs, way too costly)?

As I have read that producer/consumer contacts one of the broker nodes directly, without contacting zookeeper.

Thanks,

Viral

Answer (score 0):

Research "letsencrypt". You don't have to pay for trusted certificates. Also you can combine many domains/hostnames into one certificate

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But I also wanted to know whether zookeeper also needs to be set up with ssl cert in the use case I have illustrated ? Or the setup I have described makes sense or I have understood it wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need to have certificate created per individual Kafka broker nodes on the cluster . 
So Keystore contains key and certificate of your broker , import this to truststore signed by CA . 
Similarlu If you signed the certificate with same CA on truststore then all the clients signed by this CA already know it's authorized .

Also if you enabled ssl.client.authorize enabled then client must have it's own Keystore (key+certifcate) signed by CA on truststore

I don't think zookeeper requires a certificate .